# Why my mongodb-stitch service return me the value type ($numberLong, $numberInt,…)?

Tags: mongodb-stitch

Why my mongodb-stitch service return me the type of value ($numberLong, $numberInt,…) while the Compass application do not do ?

How to have the same varialble format like in Compas or how to handle this with Stitch ?

### Mongodb-stitch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OLdN.png)

### Compass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM60p.png)

Comment: That's just the way Stitch displays the data to you. You can interact with the values as if they were normal dates or numbers. Also, if you console.log() the values, you can see what it actually looks like without the $numberLong, $numberInt

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB Stitch functions have access to utility packages provided through various global variables.

And some of them are below: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/utilities/

JSON

EJSON

BSON

When you execute your function, response prints with EJSON.
Thats why you see your response like this at result tab, in the bottom of your response like that:

> result (JavaScript): 
>   EJSON.parse('[{"_id":{"$oid":"5bf9302f72a975ed8229fdf4"}, "rating": {"$numberDouble": "5"}, {...

Comment: It happening to me using mongoose, how do I stop this?