# MongoDB Stitch returns data as $NumberDouble instead of the number itself

Tags: mongodb, api, bson, mongodb-stitch

I'm using MongoDB Stitch to create a data enabled API, but when I make a GET request, the data is returned where numbers are displayed as:

```
"firstHit": {
   "$numberInt": "3"
```

Where I would like them to be return just as:

```
"firstHit": 3
```

I have a lot of objects within objects, and I am inserting the data through the mongo shell, I'm not sure of that is of any importance.

Anyone have any experience with this? Thank you!

Comment: Not had much experience with Stitch but another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53480188/399435) suggests you are getting back an EJSON response. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55362205/399435) for some possible suggestions on how to parse the response. If not please edit your question and add how you are making the GET request.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the result format returned by [MongoDB Stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/) webhooks is in [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format, or `EJSON` for short. This is useful to define data types that would otherwise be lost in normal JSON. There are some object types that have no equivalent in JSON, for example [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) and [Date()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/).

If you would like to return as a normal JSON, you could set the [response object](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/webhook-requests-and-responses/index.html#webhook-response-object) as an example below:

```
exports = function(payload, response) {

    result = {"firsthit": 10};

    response.setStatusCode(200);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.setBody(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

You may also find [EJSON library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejson) and [Stitch Utility Packages](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/utilities/) as useful additional information.