# MongoDB Stitch Return JSON Array Object

Tags: mongodb, stitch

How MongoDB Stitch 3rd Party Services return JSON Array Object? My return it's showing EJSON with $ (dollar sign). Someone can help me ?

```
return mycollection.findOne({"_id": BSON.ObjectId(id)});
```

response e.g.: cost: {$numberDouble: "65"}

I need e.g.: cost : 65

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.find/

To create an array try:

```
return mycollection.find({"_id": BSON.ObjectId(id)}).toArray();
```

To resolve issue with numberDouble see:
[MongoDB Stitch returns data as $NumberDouble instead of the number itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922685/mongodb-stitch-returns-data-as-numberdouble-instead-of-the-number-itself)