# BSON to relaxed JSON in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I use MongoDB Realm 3rd Party services as webhooks and can't manage to parse incoming data to normal JSON, instead it automatically parses to JSON 'strict' format giving some variables types.

```
exports = function(payload, response) {

  var data = JSON.parse(payload.body.text());

  return data
};
```

e.g. with payload:

```
{
    "key": 0,
    "text": "AlphaZero"
}
```

parsing data from BSON changes it into:

```
{
    "key": {
        "$numberDouble": "0"
    },
    "text": "AlphaZero"
}
```

How do I deal with it?

Comment: This may help, worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926733